# Log4j level not working for the root logger

Tags: java, log4j

Okay, this is driving me nuts. I have an app that uses log4j 1.2.16, my configuration file is properly picked up and log4j writes to the file that I want, BUT it only logs error level.

**Code:**

```java
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

     - (... code omitted)

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PostLoginController.class);

    LOGGER.debug("TOTO debug");
    LOGGER.info("TOTO Info");
    LOGGER.warn("TOTO warn");
    LOGGER.error("TOTO error");
```

**XML:**

```
<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log/myLogFile.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t:%c] : %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value ="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
</root>
```

When my app runs myLogFile is created and I can see the error log in it, but not the other ones:

```
2019-06-06 19:37:31 ERROR [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2:my.classpath.PostLoginController] : TOTO error
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out. I had to add

```
    <category name="my.classpath">
        <priority value="all" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </category>
```

because somehow the rootLogger level can't be altered.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this for logging debug to error.

```
<log4j:configuration debug="false">

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="target" value="System.out" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log/myLogFile.log"/>
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="default.console" />
        <appender-ref ref="default.file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Can you also post what is printed as part of logging in file ?

Comment: Ok,Great, you got to know.